# How to get document details inside a StreamBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a recipes collection from different users. I'm referencing the author of the recipe by authorId, and I need to display the author firstName alongside with the recipe

```
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                if ('${ds['authorId']}' != null) {
                  String authorName="";
                  String authorId='${ds['authorId']}';
                  print(authorId);
                  Firestore.instance.collection('Authors').document(authorId).get().then((author){
                    print(author.data);
                    if(author.data!=null)authorName=author.data["firstName"];
                  });}
```

The authorId is printed OK, but author.data is always null
Is it possible to get data from another document inside a builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `.data` after `snapshot.data.documents[index]` in line 4.